# Sahi Not working in chrome: NumberFormatException exception is occurred

Tags: google-chrome, numberformatexception, sahi

I'm trying to run the `sahi` script in Chrome. But when I click the button it throws a NumberFormatException. But it is working in Firefox.

The exception message is...

Exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "849.4500122070312"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.MouseEventDetails.deSerialize(MouseEventDetails.java:119)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java:217)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug.

I think it has to do with the mouse coordinate not being an Integer when clicking via Sahi. Could you share the URL or a sample page where this can be reproduced?

Would it be possible to try this on Sahi Pro to check if it is fixed there? It will help pinpoint the issue.